# How do I COUNT rows of a GROUP BY query where a condition matches?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count

This is my persons table:

```
neighborhood  birthyear
a             1958
a             1959
b             1970
c             1980
```

I'd like to get the `COUNT` of people in an age group within every neighborhood. For example, if I wanted to get everyone under the age of 18, I would get:

```
neighborhood  count
a             0
b             0
c             0
```

If I wanted to get everyone over 50, I'd get

```
neighborhood  count
a             2
b             0
c             0
```

I tried

```sql
SELECT neighborhood, COUNT(*)
    FROM persons
    WHERE YEAR(NOW()) - persons.birthyear < 18
    GROUP BY neighborhood;
```

but this gives me 0 rows, when instead I want 3 rows with distinct neighborhoods and 0 count for each. How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT neighborhood, SUM(YEAR(NOW()) - p.birthyear) as under_18,
       SUM(YEAR(NOW()) - p.birthyear BETWEEN 34 AND 42) as age_34_42
FROM persons p
GROUP BY neighborhood;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that if the count is 0, the row doesn't appear. 
Your code seems correct to me, if you try it on the example with age 50, it should give you one row whith the expected line (neighborhood:a,count:2)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a sub query:

```sql
SELECT 
    count(*) [group-by-count-greater-than-ten] 
FROM 
(
   SELECT 
      columnFoo, 
      count(*) cnt
   FROM barTable
   WHERE columnBaz = "barbaz"
   GROUP BY columnFoo
) 
AS subQuery
WHERE cnt > 10
```

In the above, the `subquery` return result set is being used by the `main query` as any other table.

The column `cnt` is no longer seen by the `main query` as a computed field and does not have to reference the `count()` function.

However, inside the `subquery` running a `where` clause or a `having` clause that must look at the alias `cnt` column, the `count()` function would have to be referenced as referencing `cnt` in the `subquery` would throw an error.

In your case using a `subquery` would look something like this.

```sql
SELECT 
    neighborhood, 
    age, 
    count(*) as cnt
FROM
(
     SELECT 
         *, 
         (YEAR(NOW()) - birthyear) as age 
     FROM PERSONS
) as WithAge
WHERE age < 18
GROUP BY neighborhood, age
```